# Sending post request multipart form data. Error from some microsoft service "Line length limit 100 exceeded"

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, http, axios

This data is sent from Postman and it works:

This is a postman request which passes with a 200 status:

```
POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1

Host: api.test.contoso.se

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Authorization: Basic 123

User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0

Accept: */*

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 089af753-fa12-46c4-326f-dfc39c36faab,c5977145-ece3-4b53-93ff-057788eb0dcf

Host: api.test.contoso.se

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate

content-length: 18354

Connection: keep-alive

cache-control: no-cache

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Lang"

SV
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="/C:/Users/file.docx


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Login"

ABC
```

This is my request from NodeJs via Axios:

```
    const form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("File", fs.createReadStream(pathToFile));
        form_data.append('Login', alias.toUpperCase());
        console.log(form_data); // se output down
        const request_config = {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic 123",
                "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form_data._boundary}`
            },
            data: form_data
        };
```

console.log(form_data):

```
FormData {

  _overheadLength: 540,

  _valueLength: 13,

  _valuesToMeasure:

   [ ReadStream {

       _readableState: [ReadableState],

       readable: true,

       _events: [Object],

       _eventsCount: 3,

       _maxListeners: undefined,

       path:

        '/Users/qq/test.docx',

       fd: null,

       flags: 'r',

       mode: 438,

       start: undefined,

       end: Infinity,

       autoClose: true,

       pos: undefined,

       bytesRead: 0,

       closed: false,

       emit: [Function] } ],

  writable: false,

  readable: true,

  dataSize: 0,

  maxDataSize: 2097152,

  pauseStreams: true,

  _released: false,

  _streams:

   [ '----------------------------610001147909085905792533\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="test.docx"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\r\n\r\n',

     DelayedStream {

       source: [ReadStream],

       dataSize: 0,

       maxDataSize: Infinity,

       pauseStream: true,

       _maxDataSizeExceeded: false,

       _released: false,

       _bufferedEvents: [Array],

       _events: [Object],

       _eventsCount: 1 },

     [Function: bound ],

     '----------------------------610001147909085905792533\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Login"\r\n\r\n',

     'abc',

     [Function: bound ] ],

  _currentStream: null,

  _insideLoop: false,

  _pendingNext: false,

  _boundary: '--------------------------610001147909085905792533
```

The error I get from ASP server: `Line length limit 100 exceeded`

What am I missing in my request?

Comment: check out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642701/microsoft-aspnetcore-webutilities-line-length-limit-100-exceeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities Line length limit 100 exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642701/microsoft-aspnetcore-webutilities-line-length-limit-100-exceeded)

Comment: I don't see any accepted answer.

Comment: is it a multipart form in both cases?

Comment: Yes they are both multipart

Comment: are you getting it in .net core?

Answer (score 7):

According to these two github issues:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2939

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3724

The issue is caused by a failure to use the correct line endings. I can't tell from your code *exactly* where the issue is occuring, but it should be fairly straightforward to debug it.

You need to use a proxy - I find [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to be very good. Capture the request from Postman and from your Client and compare them. You may need to drop the whole request into an editor like Notepad++ to be able to view the non-printing characters.

Once you find the issue, it should be straightforward to amend to add or remove `\r` as appropriate.

Comment: But is it a bug in my client (Axios/Form-data) or is it on the server? If it's on my side, it's not that easy to change line-endings in an external package?

Comment: Less of a bug and more of a mismatch. While the `console.log(formdata)` is useful, you really need to see the raw request in a proxy to figure out what the issue is

Comment: So what do I do when I find the error? Manually write a new form-data module and add line endings?

Comment: My first choice would be to manually serialize the body and add it to the request. Not sure if you can - that depends on the library I guess. Another option could be middleware on the server to correct the format

Comment: I find no such option in https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data. And I have no control of the serverside. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: That does seem like a tricky problem, is it possible to try a different library?

Comment: I don't find any other library. Guess I have fork the library and change the line endings. :/

Answer (score 2):

The code below setup a HTTP server at `localhost:3000`, and for all incoming requests, the server dumps the raw request body.

Try posting your request to `localhost:3000` from both Postman and Nodejs, and compare the difference.

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
    req.on("data", _ => _)
       .on("end" , _ => res.end(req.socket.rawBody));
}).on('connection', socket => {
    socket.rawBody = "";
    socket.on('data', data => socket.rawBody += data.toString());
}).listen(3000);
```

This is the sample output

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic QUJDOkFCQw==
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:3000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------540608501697240762060297
content-length: 268
Connection: keep-alive

----------------------------540608501697240762060297
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Lang"

SV
----------------------------540608501697240762060297
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Login"

ABC
----------------------------540608501697240762060297--
```

Hope this will help you debug the problem.

Comment: I did this. Check in my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848756/remove-line-breaks-form-mult-form-data-node