# Remove line breaks form mult form data. Node

Tags: node.js, rest

Data sent from Node via Mac. This fails:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------410170969577572462482590
Authorization: Basic U3dlY2q9DdlRvQ29uqdGFjdDpVM2RsWTI5RGRsUnZqRMjl1ZEdGamRB
User-Agent: axios/0.18.0
Content-Length: 437
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close

    {
  "_overheadLength": 105,
  "_valueLength": 5,
  "_valuesToMeasure": {},
  "writable": false,
  "readable": true,
  "dataSize": 0,
  "maxDataSize": 2097152,
  "pauseStreams": true,
  "_released": false,
  "_streams": {
    "0": "----------------------------097921969493700670690484\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Domain\"\r\n\r\n",
    "1": "Test"
  },
  "_currentStream": {},
  "_insideLoop": false,
  "_pendingNext": false,
  "_boundary": "--------------------------097921969493700670690484"
}
```

Data sent from Postman from Windows. This works:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------214255515908701131866697
Authorization: Basic U3dlY29DwerdlRvQ29uwerdGFjdDpVM2RsWTwerI5RGRsUnZRMjl1ZEdGamRB
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4af4ff14-1abd-4ab7-9e01-5ddd846acfa9
Host: localhost:3020
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 383
Connection: keep-alive

----------------------------214255515908701131866697
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Domain"

test
--
```

It seem's node add row brakes: `\r\n\r\n` here and there.

This causes a failure from a windows server when I post data to it: "Line length 100 exceeded".

See this question: [Sending post request multipart form data. Error from some microsoft service "Line length limit 100 exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579151/sending-post-request-multipart-form-data-error-from-some-microsoft-service-lin/56699003#56699003)

I'm using this the form-data package to post data combined with axios.

Is it possible to add some filter/middleware etc that removes alla /n/r etc in my post request?

**Update**

My request from node:

```
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('Domain', 'test');


const request_config = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dffdg",
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form_data._boundary}`
        },
        data: form_data
    };


    await axios.post(url, form_data, request_config).then(response => {
```

Comment: could you post your code showing how are you handling incoming request?

Comment: Could you show how you send the data via Node?

Comment: @Neverever I've added the node request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing `data` from `request_config`.

```
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('Domain', 'test');


const request_config = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dffdg",
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form_data._boundary}`
    },
    //data: form_data
};


await axios.post(url, form_data, request_config).then( /* ... */ )
```

from [axios/axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) documentation

> NOTE
>
> When using the alias methods **url**, **method**, and **data** properties don't need to be specified in config.

Comment: Spent so much on this and it was this easy. I was totally focused it had something to do with line breaks. Thanks!

Comment: @Neverever Could we also have explanation for this answer please?